# In the X-Men cinematic universe, is Apocalypse the first mutant?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In the movie *X-Men: Apocalypse*, it seems that Apocalypse (En Sabah Nur) is the first mutant ever, given that he was alive around 3600 BC.

Is there any canon information from the cinematic universe, that proves Apocalypse being the first mutant?

Comment: doesn't moira make this exact claim in her office?

Comment: @KutuluMike - Sure, but was she there (in 5000BC) to check?

Comment: Moira makes the claim that he is *believed* to have been the first, making it a little fuzzy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The official marketing material confirms this.

Directly from [the movie's official website:](http://www.foxmovies.com/movies/x-men-apocalypse)

> Since the dawn of civilization, he was worshipped as a god. **Apocalypse, the first and most powerful mutant from Marvel’s X-Men universe**, amassed the powers of many other mutants, becoming immortal and invincible.

In-movie, it is *believed* that he was the first mutant. From [the transcript:](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men:_Apocalypse)

> Moira: Ever since the world found out about mutants in '73, there have been cults who see them as some kind of second coming or sign of god. I was tracking one of them. They called themselves, Ashir En Sabah Nur, named after an ancient being they believed to be the world's first.
>
> Alex: The world first's what?
>
> Moira: The world's first mutant.
>
> Alex: I thought mutants didn't evolve until this century.
>
> Moira: That's the common theory, yes. But, these guys believe that the first mutant was born tens of thousands of years ago. And they believe he will rise again. They've been searching ancient sites all round the world for clues. These hieroglyphs described a specific set of powers greater than any man can possess.

To-date, there is nothing to contradict the idea that En Sabah Nur is the world's first mutant in the X-Men Cinematic Universe.

Answer (score 1):

In the comic series, it is said that Apocalypse is the first mutant. But there is no obvious solid statement supporting this. However the cinematic universe is quite different from the comic series so nothing definitive is given. But based on the overall plot and circumstance of the show, yes, Apocalypse is the first mutant.

Comment: KyloRen explicitly asks about the *cinematic universe*. Can you update your answer to reflect this?